# How to add to iTunes Connect users, when phone number is Apple Id

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

One of our testers have their phone number as their Apple Id instead of an Email Id. This person doesn't have an Email Id signed in his phone.

But when I go to Add App Store Connect User, there's only a field to enter Email Id? Does he have to sign out and create an Apple Id with an Email Id?

I need to add this person to TestFlight.

Comment: Have you checked by adding phone number in the place of email? Is it accepting phone or not?

Comment: No, but how would that work since they email a verification link to the entered email Id?

Comment: I think you have to try it for once.

Comment: I just did... The email address you entered is invalid. Please try again.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution? For me also our tester is having a mobile number as apple id and there is no option on testflight to add their mobile number to invite them to test our app.

Comment: I haven't done any iOS lately, but I remember that our tester added an @icloud.com email Id to her phone and gave that to me. At the time when I asked the question, adding users by phone number to iTunes connect was not available to some countries like mine (India). Maybe it has changed now. Google it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You can invite a TestFlight user using any email they have access to. You don't need to invite them using their Apple ID email.

The invitation email will contain a code that they redeem using the TestFlight app. Once they redeem the code it is linked to the Apple ID that is currently logged in to the App Store on their device.

If your tester doesn't have access to any email at all then you can send the invitation to an email you have access to and then get the redemption code to them some other way; text message, owl post etc.

To add an external tester without adding them as an AppStore Connect user:

1. Go to "Test Flight" in App Store Connect
2. Create a new group by selecting "New Group"on the left
3. Select your new group and then tap "+" to add a tester.
4. Enter their name and email address

To allow an external tester to test your app you will need to submit it for beta review;

1. Select your build in Test Flight
2. Add your group or individual tester
3. Submit for review and wait for approval (typically less than a day or so)

Subsequent builds in the same version don't need to go through review, but subsequent versions will.

Comment: From my understanding, we need to add a user in iTunes Connect under 'Users and Roles' then in My Apps > My App Name > Test Flight > App Store Connect Users > , we invite the above added user to testflight (after he/she has activated their itunes connect account). This is how I've been doing all this time. And to add a user to Users and Roles, they must have an apple id. I don't understand how we can add a user to TestFlight without an apple id. Please provide a detailed answer.

Comment: If the user doesn't have an email based Apple ID you can't add them as an internal tester. You can add any email address as an "external tester".

Comment: As of 2022 there seems to no longer be a redeem code in the invite email from Apple. However, opening the invitation mail sent to non-appleid-email directly on an iPhone with TestFlight installed allowed our tester to access the test build.

Comment: If you click on the link in the invite email on a pc or Mac (not an ios device) it will take you to a web page with the redemption code